# Fetch array with mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT Name from lottery");
// Make All Lotteries Into An Array
$queryarray = mysql_fetch_array($query);
// For Each Lottery, Store the Name of It in $lottery
foreach ($queryarray as $lottery) {
    // Select IDs of Tickets in Current Selected Lottery ($lottery)
    $ticketquery = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE lottery='$lottery'");
    // Create an Array from the IDS
    $ticketarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($ticketquery);
    // Select A Random ID, This Is Our Winner Ticket
    $winner = $ticketarray[array_rand($ticketarray)];
}
```

When I run this, however, I get this error:

---

"Warning: array_rand() [function.array-rand]: First argument has to be an array in public_html/php/lotterypick.php on line 25"

---

I have tried to replace `mysql_fetch_assoc` with `mysql_fetch_array` and that hasn't helped much either. Just given me the same error. Any ideas? Thanks.

Line 25: `$winner = $ticketarray[array_rand($ticketarray)];`

Comment: You really should learn about SQL joins...

Comment: Put `var_dump($queryarray);die;` before the loop, and see what it contains... it does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: Oh wow. Yeah, that is definitely not what I thought. How would I fix that? @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: But I don't understand how combing rows from the tables would solve this issue? Or would it? @eggyal

Comment: By selecting from the joined tables, you wouldn't need to do what you're attempting at all... although you may of course still make a similar mistake.

Comment: If I had both tables joined I would still have to get the names of the lotteries, and then for each name/lottery I would still have to get the ids of all the tickets and select a random id then keep doing this for each lottery until there is a winner in each one. If the tables were joined I'd still have to do the same thing just without having to select them from different tables, right? @eggyal

Comment: @TonyStark: Or you could just ask MySQL to select a random ticket from each lottery, as one query.

Comment: Could you give an example of this? I'm just not understanding how this works.... @eggyal

Comment: How about directly writing something like this: `while($lottery = mysql_fetch_array($query)){...}`

Comment: Absolutely perfect!!! Thank you so much! Could you make it an answer? Thanks again! @bayblade567

Comment: @TonyStark...did ! :)

Comment: @eggyal he should be learning PDO also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the code as:

```
while($lottery = mysql_fetch_array($query)){...}
```

would solve the problem.